# how to run firebase query inside a function in node js

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a function which should query firebase db and return a result.

```
 function verifyToken(token)
 {
    var androidId = 'xxxxx';
    admin.database(dbDEV).ref('profiles').orderByChild('androidId').equalTo(androidId).on('value',(snapshot)=>{
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    return snapshot.val();
   });
 }
```

I am using firebase functions for this . so the result is getting logged in firebase logs but i am not getting and return value while executing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Use once() instead of on() to query data a single time.  on() establishes a listener that listens forever, until you remove the listener.
- Realtime Database queries are all asynchronous, meaning they return immediately, and the callback function you provide is invoked some time later with the results.  You can't simply return the results from the callback in order to return those results from the enclosing function.  If you want verifyToken to yield query results to the caller, you should return a promise that resolves with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using promises. For example:

```
function verifyToken(token) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var androidId = 'xxxxx';
        admin.database(dbDEV).ref('profiles').orderByChild('androidId').equalTo(androidId).on('value',(snapshot)=>{
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            resolve(snapshot.val());
        });
    });
}
```

And when you need the result:

```
verifyToken(token).then(result => {
    ... do stuff
});
```

To improve on this, you can use an async function. For example:

```
async function foo() {
    const result = await verifyToken(token);
    console.log(result);
}
```